# Create multiple columns based on leads or lags of other time series columns

Tags: r

Have a problem, need your help. I have a data which can be treated as a panel but is a little bit different as there may be 'multiple time series' for each `ID`, see example below

```
set.seed(100)
## create data
mydf<-data.frame(ID = c(rep('A',7),rep('B',3)),
                 year =c(c(2001:2003),c(2006:2009),c(2001:2003)),
                 x = rnorm(10),
                 y = rnorm(10))

 mydf
    ID year           x           y
 1:  A 2001 -0.50219235  0.08988614
 2:  A 2002  0.13153117  0.09627446
 3:  A 2003 -0.07891709 -0.20163395
 4:  A 2006  0.88678481  0.73984050
 5:  A 2007  0.11697127  0.12337950
 6:  A 2008  0.31863009 -0.02931671
 7:  A 2009 -0.58179068 -0.38885425
 8:  B 2001  0.71453271  0.51085626
 9:  B 2002 -0.82525943 -0.91381419
10:  B 2003 -0.35986213  2.31029682
```

For some particular reasons, I would like to keep all the time series of each `ID` with at least three consecutive observations, hence may lead to multiple time series for one `ID`, as you can see that there are two time series of `ID == A` satisfy this condition. I want to create leads and lags of variables `x`,`y`.

If there is only one consecutive time series for each `ID`, I could simply use:

```
anscols.Lead1=paste("Lead.1",c('x','y'),sep="_")
mydf[,(anscols.Lead1):=shift(.SD,1,NA,type="lead"),.SDcols=c('x','y'),by=ID]
```

Or if I need to operate on only one column, I could also use:

```
tp.mydf<-pdata.frame(mydf,c("ID","year"))
tp.mydf$lag1x<-lag(tp.mydf$x)
```

However, with non - consecutive time series and multiple columns, data.table way won't work (result):

```
mydf
    ID year           x           y    Lead.1_x    Lead.1_y
 1:  A 2001 -0.50219235  0.08988614  0.13153117  0.09627446
 2:  A 2002  0.13153117  0.09627446 -0.07891709 -0.20163395
 3:  A 2003 -0.07891709 -0.20163395  0.88678481  0.73984050
 4:  A 2006  0.88678481  0.73984050  0.11697127  0.12337950
 5:  A 2007  0.11697127  0.12337950  0.31863009 -0.02931671
 6:  A 2008  0.31863009 -0.02931671 -0.58179068 -0.38885425
 7:  A 2009 -0.58179068 -0.38885425          NA          NA
 8:  B 2001  0.71453271  0.51085626 -0.82525943 -0.91381419
 9:  B 2002 -0.82525943 -0.91381419 -0.35986213  2.31029682
10:  B 2003 -0.35986213  2.31029682          NA          NA
```

What I want is:

```
mydf
    ID year           x           y    Lead.1_x    Lead.1_y
 1:  A 2001 -0.50219235  0.08988614  0.13153117  0.09627446
 2:  A 2002  0.13153117  0.09627446 -0.07891709 -0.20163395
 3:  A 2003 -0.07891709 -0.20163395          NA          NA
 4:  A 2006  0.88678481  0.73984050  0.11697127  0.12337950
 5:  A 2007  0.11697127  0.12337950  0.31863009 -0.02931671
 6:  A 2008  0.31863009 -0.02931671 -0.58179068 -0.38885425
 7:  A 2009 -0.58179068 -0.38885425          NA          NA
 8:  B 2001  0.71453271  0.51085626 -0.82525943 -0.91381419
 9:  B 2002 -0.82525943 -0.91381419 -0.35986213  2.31029682
10:  B 2003 -0.35986213  2.31029682          NA          NA
```

Any one know how to fix this?

================== EDIT, totaly based on Shah's answer, just for clarity for those followers to check:

```
mydf.newgrp<-mydf %>%
  group_by(ID, group = cumsum(c(T, diff(year) != 1))) 
setDT(mydf.newgrp)
anscols.Lead1=paste("Lead.1",c('x','y'),sep="_")
mydf.newgrp[,(anscols.Lead1):=shift(.SD,1,NA,type="lead"),.SDcols=c('x','y'),by=group]
mydf.newgrp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dplyr` we can create a new grouping variable (`group`) where the difference between two `year` values is greater than 1. We then group by `ID` and `group` and then calculate the `lead` values.

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
  group_by(ID, group = cumsum(c(T, diff(year) != 1))) %>%
  mutate(Lead_x = lead(x), Lead_y = lead(y)) %>%
  select(-group)


#   group ID     year     x       y   Lead_x   Lead_y
#   <int> <fct> <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     1 A      2001 -0.502   0.0899   0.132    0.0963
# 2     1 A      2002  0.132   0.0963 - 0.0789 - 0.202 
# 3     1 A      2003 -0.0789 -0.202      NA       NA     
# 4     2 A      2006  0.887   0.740    0.117    0.123 
# 5     2 A      2007  0.117   0.123    0.319  - 0.0293
# 6     2 A      2008  0.319  -0.0293 - 0.582  - 0.389 
# 7     2 A      2009 -0.582  -0.389       NA       NA     
# 8     3 B      2001  0.715   0.511  - 0.825  - 0.914 
# 9     3 B      2002 -0.825  -0.914  - 0.360    2.31  
#10     3 B      2003 -0.360   2.31        NA       NA
```

---

If there are lot of columns which we need to select we can use `mutate_at`

```
cols <- c("x", "y")
mydf %>%
   group_by(ID, group = cumsum(c(T, diff(year) != 1))) %>%
   mutate_at(cols, .funs = funs(lead = lead(.))) %>%
   select(-group)


#  group1 ID     year       x       y   x_lead   y_lead
#    <int> <fct> <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1      1 A      2001 -0.502   0.0899   0.132    0.0963
# 2      1 A      2002  0.132   0.0963 - 0.0789 - 0.202 
# 3      1 A      2003 -0.0789 -0.202       NA       NA     
# 4      2 A      2006  0.887   0.740    0.117    0.123 
# 5      2 A      2007  0.117   0.123    0.319  - 0.0293
# 6      2 A      2008  0.319  -0.0293 - 0.582  - 0.389 
# 7      2 A      2009 -0.582  -0.389       NA       NA     
# 8      3 B      2001  0.715   0.511  - 0.825  - 0.914 
# 9      3 B      2002 -0.825  -0.914  - 0.360    2.31  
#10      3 B      2003 -0.360   2.31        NA       NA
```

The output of grouping variable `group` comes out to be

```
cumsum(c(T, diff(mydf$year) != 1)) 
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

Comment: @Shah great, I was thinking about creating new groups but stuck with how to do it. Any thought on how to simplify your answer if one has one hundred columns to manipulate, i.e. `mutate(a hundred columns here)`?

Comment: @JasonGoal I have updated the solution. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @Shah, not all the remaining columns, and given speed and convenience of data.table, I'll combine your method with data.table solution, for clarity, I put them in the question part. And will accept yours as answer.

Comment: @Shah, together with the updated solution, yours solved my question totally.

Answer (score 3):

With `data.table`, we can change the `by` to include the grouping variable

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, paste0("Lead.1_", names(mydf)[3:4]) := 
    shift(.SD, type = 'lead'), by = .(ID, cumsum(year - shift(year, fill = year[1]) != 1))]
mydf
#    ID year           x           y    Lead.1_x    Lead.1_y
# 1:  A 2001 -0.50219235  0.08988614  0.13153117  0.09627446
# 2:  A 2002  0.13153117  0.09627446 -0.07891709 -0.20163395
# 3:  A 2003 -0.07891709 -0.20163395          NA          NA
# 4:  A 2006  0.88678481  0.73984050  0.11697127  0.12337950
# 5:  A 2007  0.11697127  0.12337950  0.31863009 -0.02931671
# 6:  A 2008  0.31863009 -0.02931671 -0.58179068 -0.38885425
# 7:  A 2009 -0.58179068 -0.38885425          NA          NA
# 8:  B 2001  0.71453271  0.51085626 -0.82525943 -0.91381419
# 9:  B 2002 -0.82525943 -0.91381419 -0.35986213  2.31029682
#10:  B 2003 -0.35986213  2.31029682          NA          NA
```

If there are other columns that are doesn't need to be `shift`ed, we can specify the `.SDcols`

```
nm1 <- names(mydf)[3:4]
setDT(mydf)[, paste0("Lead.1_", nm1) := 
    shift(.SD, type = 'lead'), 
   by = .(ID, cumsum(year - shift(year, fill = year[1]) != 1)), .SDcols = nm1]
```

Comment: Shah's solution came earlier than yours and it did solve my major problem, that's I why I took that one as the answer. But your stuff is something really cool to me,  never aware that kind of manipulation of the `by` argument in `data.table`.  And two lines less than what I posted. Really cool, I recommend this way.

Comment: @JasonGoal  No problem.  I think the credit should be to RonakShah's solution.  I was just using similar methodology to implement in data.table